# Batchload items form a DynamoDB table using gloabalSecondaryIndex(GSI)

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a DynamoDB table having field X as a GSI hash key, I what query this table to fetch all documents where the field X has value contained in the list xList = ["a", "b", "c"]. what is the best way to query this using DynamoDBMapper?

Right now I use the following code for this senario,

```
List<TableDoc> tableDocs = xList.stream().map( x -> new TableDocument().setX(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String, List<Object>> result = dynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(tableDocs);
```

I have documents in the table corresponding to the x values in xList, But I get null when I do

```
result.get(TABLE_NAME);
```

Is this a right way of batchloading items using GSIs?

Thanks for reading :)